# Facetime Imposter

Tags: facetime

Phone rang, Facetime identified my daughter as the caller. I answered, but it was not my daughter. I saw the caller. Once the caller saw me, she freaked out and hung up. In my "recents" the call was identified as from my daughter. What's up with that?

Comment: Change AppleID Password on your Daughters device. At least, she has to do it. (you don't have to)

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me one time.  I made a FaceTime call, and it connected to a complete stranger.  We both freaked out.

I had an old, stale cell phone number still attached to the person I was calling.  I suspect, but could not verify, that the number had been re-used and the new owner attached it to a different Apple ID.  FaceTime decided for some reason to place the call to the wrong Apple ID.

I deleted the old phone number.  Since then, I've never had any trouble making this FaceTime call.

Answer (score 0):

You only need your Apple ID to register for Facetime, so it sounds like one of your daughter's friends was playing around with her iPhone/iPad/iPod/Mac.

Or your daughter sold it, and forgot to log out of her Apple ID before handing her device over.

Another scenario could be that she logged into Facetime on a friend's Mac with her own Apple ID, and it's still logged in.

Could any of those situations be it?